# How can you create Time-Series Plots with different countries

Tags: python

I am tasked with creating a function that contains 3 countries (US, Canada and China) as my inputs and then creating subplots with their COVID cases. I wanted to know how to best do this, as I was thinking of creating a dataframe with those countries and then running a for loop within to create the subplots. Please provide some tips and tricks as to how to complete this task.

The code that I am stuck on is down below as well as the error message.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame(data=cases_raw).rename_axis("Country").reset_index()
df
df.index.tolist() #returns the list of countries 
A = cases_raw.loc['US'] 
B = cases_raw.loc['China'] 
C = cases_raw.loc['Canada'] 

#Make US,China and Canada as inputs and create sub-plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,4), sharey=True)
country_groups = df.groupby("Country")
#country_name = []
for (country_name, ax) in zip(country_groups.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
  country_groups.get_group(country_name).plot(ax=ax, title=country_name)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the error. Also, you should ask a specific question, this isn't a site for getting "tips and tricks" or general advice on how to design something. You should have an objective question about code itself, that can be answered objectively.

Comment: My apologies, there was no error message. I just received a messed up plot like the one you see above. With the code above, I want to know how you could create specific plots for countries like US, Canada & China.